# How would one get the data from a remembered form from a web browser?

Tags: forms, ember.js

As an example, I'm creating a login page.

Chrome asked me if I'd like it to remember the password, and I did, so I let it fill in the form.

I validate against the form and check if fields are empty when the user clicks the send button or presses enter, but I can't seem to grab the data from the form that Chrome has filled out.  Events aren't being fired that would cause the properties bound to the fields be updated when the browser fills in the fields for the user.

I've attempted to just use a jQuery selector to get the value in `didInsertElement()`, but the browser fills the field after that function is called.

```
App.LoginView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this._super();
        var usernameInput = jQuery("#usernameInput").val();
        var passwordInput = jQuery("#passwordInput").val();
        if (usernameInput) this.set('controller.username', usernameInput);
        if (passwordInput) this.set('controller.password', passwordInput);
    }
});
```

---

**Edit:**

I wrapped the section that grabs the values from the fields in `Ember.run.next()`:

```
App.LoginView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this._super();
        var loginView = this;
        Ember.run.next(function() {
            var usernameInput = jQuery("#usernameInput").val();
            var passwordInput = jQuery("#passwordInput").val();
            if (usernameInput) loginView.set('controller.username', usernameInput);
            if (passwordInput) loginView.set('controller.password', passwordInput);
        });
    }
});
```

This seems to have done the trick, but I don't know if it's a robust solution.  After testing just a little bit, it seems to work.  I'll wait to post an answer and select it, in case anyone else has a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for emptiness after user's click on "send" button (or press Enter) for this case.

Comment: That's the issue that I'm having.  I check for the emptiness of the fields when sending, but because the browser is filling in the fields,  my bounded properties are not being updated as they would if the user would type in them themselves.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. :) Check this issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4524 It seems, your problem solves only by dirty hacks for now.

Comment: Thank you.  I'd prefer not the poll the fields, since it's really not that big of a pain.  I've updated my question with a possible answer.